# Does R have a Set data structure?

Tags: r, data-structures, set

I have a large vector variable holding exactly 5000 elements, and would like to know what these are, knowing that there are several repetitions. [An introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) doesn't seem to say anything besides basic data structures, and I don't know if R offers this feature as built-in.

If there is no such data structure, is there some built-in function to filter out repeated elements in a vector or list?

Comment: if your vector or list is x, unique(x) returns the unique values. In the case of a dataframe it returns unique rows.

Comment: If by "data structure" you mean how many elements are for each value, then you could try this `library(data.table); dt <- data.table(v1=c(rep(1,2500),rep(2,2500))); dt[,.N,v1]`

Comment: What if I want to have absence of duplicated elements even while I'm adding into a vector, list or some other data structure? From what I have learned so far it doesn't seem easy to dynamically extend data structures, but to me the problem still applies.

Comment: You could use a hashmap, whose keys are basically a set, if that might help.

Comment: @quant By the way, the term *data structure* seems to be part of the standard jargon in R, at least from what I read. Section 2.1 of *An introduction to R* reads exactly «R operates on named *data structures*. [...]». Am I allowed to remove the quotes to *data structure* inside my question?

Comment: No need for quotes. If you have items that are repeated many times, then `table` can be pretty useful. When fed a single vector, it returns a table with the original values as names and the counts of each element as values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove multiple occurrences of a value within a vector use `duplicated()`

an example would be

```
x <- c(1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6)
x[!duplicated(x)]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

This is returning all values of `x` which are not (`!`) duplicated.

This will also work for more complex data structures like `data.frames`. See `?duplicated` for further information.

`unique(x)` provides all values occurring in the vector.

`table(x)` shows the unqiue values and their number of occurrences in vector `x`

```
table(x)
# x
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 1 1 2 1 2 1
```

Comment: The implemetion above is not full represantion of set, as it should possess proporty that set(1,2)=set(2,1), order is not important.

Answer (score 3):

`unique()` function will work.

```
unique("name of vector")
```

Comment: `unique(my_vector)` does the trick for me; returns only unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also recommend looking into the [`sets`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sets/index.html) library. Install it with `install.packages('sets')` and see, if the following works for you.

```
sets::as.set(c(1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5))
# output: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```